# Add config.txt to docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We have a war which needs a configuration file to work. 
We want to dockerize it. At the moment we're doing the following:

```
FROM tomcat:8.0
COPY apps/test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
COPY conf/ /config/
```

Our containers is losing the advantages of docker because it's dependent of the configfile. So when we want to execute the .war for other purposes we have to recreate the image which isn't a good approach.

Is it possible to give a config-file as a parameter without mounting it as a volume? Because we don't want the config on our local machine. What could be a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as an `ENV` but I don't see you losing the advantages of Docker. Docker is essentially all about temporary containers that are dispensable. Ideally you want to build a new image for every new app version.

Comment: The .war is using a .txt which contains parameters. It isn't using environment variables

Comment: You can have a script that will write the content of the `ENV` to a `.war` and then use it. This was my original idea.